# showing array value in laravel blade

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I'm including a return from a database in my controller into my blade

when I dump it

```
<?php dd($count)?>
```

I get

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "STORES" => "40"
  ]
]
```

But in the blade where I have

```
Count: {{$count['STORES']}}
```

It shows Count: and then it's blank after that. The database return only ever returns one count and I'd like to get this working to say "If return is null, set $count['STORES'] = 1, else use $count['STORES']

Comment: Count: {{$count[0]['STORES']}} - array in array ?

Comment: YES! Thanks, That got it. Is there anyway to throw something in there as well that just uses a 1 for that value if it happens to return null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a multidimensional array.  There is no key "STORES" at the 1st level.  Only the Key 0.  The blade should be

```
Count: {{$count[0]['STORES']}}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way in that same area to say if the value is null then use 1 as 'STORES' ?

Comment: {{ $count[0]['STORES'] or 1 }}

Comment: OH wow, didn't realize I could do something that simple. Thanks@